# Trying to mock an API class with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to learn how to use RSpec to test that my create_price_type_cache method on the Setting class is being called by the API class instance. I've tried a number of approaches I've googled, but I figure out how to do this, or even if I should write my API class differently.

The test below gives me the error:

```
undefined method `api_endpoint' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000107376420>


# setting_spec.rb
it "should call get_price_type_list from the API" do
  price_types = [build(:price_type)]

  api = mock_model(Api.instance)
  api.stub!(:get_price_type_list).and_return(price_types)
  expect(Api.instance.should_recieve(:get_price_type_list).and_return(api)).to eq [price_types]
end

# setting.rb
class Setting
  def self.create_price_type_cache
    array = Api.instance.get_price_type_list
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      CachePriceType.delete_all
      array.each do |e|
        e.save!
      end
    end
  end
end

# api.rb
class Api
  def self.instance
    @instance ||= new
  end

  def get_price_type_list
    # Makes an API call and returns an array of objects
  end
end
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Thank you jstim for waking me up, I confused myself after looking at this for so long. I've stubbed out the config settings for my Api class and this seems to be working, but is that the best way to do it, or should I mock the Api class like I originally tried?

This is my current passing test:

```
Rails.application.config.stub(:api_endpoint).and_return("")
price_types = [build(:cache_price_type)]
Api.instance.stub(:get_price_type_list).and_return([price_types])
Array.any_instance.stub(:save!)
expect {Setting.create_price_type_cache}.to_not raise_error
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are calling a mock in your expectation. That is where you should be calling `Setting.create_price_type_cache`. I don't know if that will pass the test, but it's the first issue that pops out at me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure if this is the best approach, since I'll have to stub every config setting in my Api class, but this is what I ended up using as my final test for now:

```
Rails.application.config.stub(:api_endpoint).and_return("")
price_types = [build(:cache_price_type)]
Api.instance.stub(:get_price_type_list).and_return([price_types])
Array.any_instance.stub(:save!)
expect {Setting.create_price_type_cache}.to_not raise_error
```